# SSH session dies on remote machine after detaching using TMUX

Tags: ssh, tmux

I have a few scripts running on a remote machine that I have ssh access to. I connect on my local machine (Mac) in terminal using TMUX. I create a new session using `$ tmux new` and ssh into the machine. I start my scripts and everything is great. I detach using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> and the scripts continue running. However, after my local machine gets rebooted or goes to sleep, the scripts on the remote machine stop. When I reload the the session using `tmux attach -t <session name>` I see the following error:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to <remote ip> port 22: Broken pipe
```

That suggests that the session ended. What can I do to ensure that the scripts continue to run no matter what happens on my local machine?

Comment: Run `tmux` on the remote end, not locally.

Comment: So I need to ssh into the remote machine, then open a TMUX session? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: I second @melpomene's comment. `tmux` must run on the remote server

Comment: when you run ssh to remote server and disconnect your machine from internet( poweroff ). Then server will break the session resulting in broken pipe. That's why tmux can't resume already ended session